# multithreading stuck at while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, fft

The purpose of this code is to compute and average the FFT of samples from a SDR. Multithreading is used to average the FFT spectrum as soon as there are data available in the array in order to save time. The code is stuck at the second while loop at line 29(no errors). I am sure about this because I have tried removing the multithreading and therefore the while loops and the rest of the code works fine. The solution to this problem seems to be adding a print command, shown below. Why?

```
sdr = RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate = 2.4e6
sdr.center_freq = 1420e6     
sdr.freq_correction = 1  
sdr.gain = 40.2
num_points= 1024
integration_time= 5
block_duration=num_points/sdr.sample_rate
num_spectra=int(integration_time/block_duration)
freq_res=sdr.sample_rate/num_points
start_freq=sdr.center_freq-(sdr.sample_rate/2)
stop_freq=sdr.center_freq+(sdr.sample_rate/2)

raw_spectra=[]
sum_arr=[]

def generate():
    for _ in range(num_spectra):
        raw_samples=sdr.read_samples(num_points)*np.hamming(num_points)
        spectra=(abs(np.fft.fft(raw_samples)))**2
        raw_spectra.append(spectra)

def average():
    zero_arr=[]
    for _ in range(num_points):
        zero_arr.append(0)
    counter=0
    while counter!=num_spectra:
        while len(raw_spectra)==0:
            continue
        zero_arr=zero_arr+raw_spectra[0]
        del raw_spectra[0]
        counter+=1
    sum_arr.append(zero_arr)

p1=threading.Thread(target=generate)
p2=threading.Thread(target=average)
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()


##Solution##
while len(raw_spectra)==0:
    print(0)
    continue
```

Comment: You don't have any kind of synchronization. Your code is full of data races so the behavior of the program is random. You need to synchronize shared data with atomic variables, mutexes or any other synchronization primitive.

Answer (score 0):

This part in the `average`-method is problematic:

```py
    while counter!=num_spectra:
        while len(raw_spectra)==0:
            continue # infinite-loop right here
```

The `continue` here refers to the inner loop so it just loops forever.

If `len(raw_spectra)==0` ever happens, you'll get stuck :)

Comment: Yep, I understand. When there is no spectra available to average, it's supposed to loop again. When there is spectra appended to the raw_spectra in the generate method, it will exit the loop. Adding a print statement somehow fixed the 'loops forever' problem, not sure why.